# WPF Datagrid changes its behavoiurs after installing VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, visual-studio-2012, wpfdatagrid, migrate

We have a WPF project that was been compiling in VS2010 until now. We installed VS2012 and opened our project within it, and then we have detected the following issue:

We have some Datagrids with AutogenerateColumn property set to true. When we added new columns to this datagrid only these new columns were shown (it had to be a wrong behavior). After installing VS2012, both new and autogenerated columns are being shown (as expected). It also happens, since then, compiling our project in VS2010 as in VS2012. We are sure that all our directly referenced assemblies are still in 4.0 version of .NET Framework, not in 4.5 version and that we have change absolutely no code.

We are not worried about this particular issue in WPF DataGrids, because it´s easily fixable by setting AutogenerateColumns to false. We are worried about which indirect reference can have been changed during VS2012 install, and what other impact can it have in our application.

We know that, in theory, no impact is expected, but we have seen this issue and our faith is teetering right now.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Gus, I would like to help help take a look. Could you email me at netfx45compat at microsoft dot com with code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested what you say in two different ways and in both of them the app has been **compiled** in the same machine (VS2012 and VS2010 installed) using VS2010 IDE and targeting .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.

In the first scenario I have **executed** this app in a machine with VS2012 installed (the one in which it was compiled) and this is the result:

[image]

As you see in this image there are two explicitly added columns ("CANTIDAD PENDIENTE" and "FECHA") and two autogenerated columns ("P1" and "P2" based on the actual properties of the anonymous object I have used as ItemsSource). This is, so, what you explain in your question.

The second scenario has been a little bit different. I have executed the **same** compiled app in another machine in which VS2012 (neither .NET 4.5 Framework) has been installed and the result obtained is worrying:

[image]

I think you should test your entire application in order to be sure you are not delivering a wrong app depending on which framework is installed on costumer environments, but obviously it can be a real headache.

I really hope this helps to clarify your issue.

Comment: @anticol Hi Folks, I would like to help help take a look. Could you email me at netfx45compat at microsoft dot com with code to reproduce the problem?